# How to SELECT DISTINCT [model].* using Squeel and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, squeel

Out of interest, i was attempting to rewrite

```
Model.joins{other_model}.uniq
```

(which generates):

```
=> "SELECT DISTINCT [model].* FROM [model] INNER JOIN [other_model] ON [other_model].[model_id] = [model].[id]"
```

In pure Squeel, however the closest i can get is

```
Model.joins{other_model}.select{distinct(id)}
```

Which generates:

```
=> "SELECT DISTINCT [model].[id] FROM [model] INNER JOIN [other_model] ON [other_model].[model_id] = [model].[id]"
```

How would i do a `DISTINCT [model].*` in Squeel? Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the * in backticks

```rb
Model.select{distinct(`*`)}.to_sql
```

Produces:

```sql
SELECT distinct(*) from `models`
```

Comment: While the `to_sql` looks right, actually running the query produces: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Incorrect syntax near '*'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT distinct(*) FROM [models]'`

Comment: Yeah well that depends on the database. MySQL accepts distinct(*), with postgres you'd need to say `models.*` within the backtick.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you pass wildcard char instead?

```
Model.joins{other_model}.select{distinct('*')}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your code produces the following SQL: `SELECT distinct(N'*') FROM [model] INNER JOIN [other_model] ON [other_model].[model_id] = [model].[id]` which just returns `*`